# Drawimage is not drawing the x,y position of the image correctly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent, drawimage

I'm trying to draw an image onto the canvas using drawimage:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
```

However, the image appears to be drawing at a position(20, 40) relative to the top left of the canvas. I want it to be drawn at (20,20).

Here is a JS fiddle that illustrates the problem:
https://codepen.io/kapooky/pen/PoYzXeL

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
//var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,300,300);

function getCursorPosition(event) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;
  // I've included helpful print statements for debugging purposes
  console.log("x: " + mouseX + " y: " + mouseY);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  getCursorPosition(e);
});
```

Comment: Don't use css `width` `height` styles to set the canvas's dimensions it will stretch the canvas. Use the object properties or html attributes to set the dimensions,eg `canvas.width=300`, `<canvas width="300">`

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be working now, thanks!